# Как отменить поведение предшествующей функции?

Tags: javascript

мой html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="element">
                <button>кнопка</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

css

```
.container {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}

.element {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px #000 solid;
}
```

js

```
function container() {
    let element = document.querySelector('.container');
    let insertion = document.createElement('p');
    insertion.append('сработала функция container()');
    element.append(insertion);
}

function element() {
    let element = document.querySelector('.element');
    let insertion = document.createElement('p');
    insertion.append('сработала функция element() при нажатии на кнопку');
    element.append(insertion);
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    document.querySelector('.container').addEventListener('click', container);
    document.querySelector('.element button').addEventListener('click', element);
})
```

Как я могу сделать так - чтобы элемент `.container` не срабатывал когда я нажимаю на кнопку?

Comment: что значит *"чтобы элемент .container не срабатывал когда я нажимаю на кнопку?"* ?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский у меня есть некий функционал который привязан к `<div class="container">` элементу, и есть функционал который привязан к лежащей в нем кнопке - и мне нужно чтобы я мог отключить действие функции `container()` когда нажимаю на кнопку. Сейчас получается так что сначала срабатывает кнопка а потом действие привязанное к  `<div class="container">` - мне же нужно чтобы когда я нажимал на кнопку - срабатывало действие только саймой кнопки и далее потом ничего не происходило

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простое решение: отменить [всплытие](https://learn.javascript.ru/event-bubbling)

```
function element(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
```